# How to record how long spend in each kind of task?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

On Teamcity, my project's build log looks like this:

```
[Build] MSBuild (28s)
    [CoreCompile] Csc (6s)
    [RunCodeAnalysis] CodeAnalysis (11s)
    [StyleCop] StyleCopTask (9s)

[Build] MSBuild (9s)
    [CoreCompile] Csc
    [RunCodeAnalysis] CodeAnalysis (8s)
    [StyleCop] StyleCopTask
```

That's a simplified extract, the full log is thousands of lines long. Anyway, those lines show how long was spent in each msbuild task (if the time in brackets is omitted, I understand that means it took less than one second).

Is it possible for Teamcity to plot this information in a graph, accumulating similar tasks? So for the example above, the graph would show 6 seconds for C# compiler, 19 seconds for CodeAnalysis, and 9 seconds for StyleCop.

For projects with multiple 'build steps', Teamcity shows the time spent in each step in a table under the 'PerfMon' tab. I like that. But my project is one long 'build step' (msbuild). I want to know how time is spent within it.

Motivation: our build is very slow. I'm curious how long is being spent in Style Cop and Code Analysis, compared to actually compiling code (Csc is the C# compiler).

Comment: have you tried teamcity service messages http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity You can then add them as custom graphs

Comment: I'd rather not change the build scripts, I was hoping Teamcity could do this itself. It already knows how long is being spent in each task, I want it to sum up similar tasks and plot a table or graph.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible without modifying a bit the build process because the buildlog is stored in an internal format (in `.BuildServer\system\messages`). I guess the displayed duration is done by parsing the buildlog (`[HH:mm:ss]: \t` ...). PerfMon works because the monitoring is done at a process level and each build step is run in a separated process. The only way I see is : **1)** Populating custom build metrics through *teamcity-info.xml or Services Messages* as James said, **2)** Use *Custom Charts* to show your build steps duration in the project statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with a simple console output, try to call MsBuild with the [PerformanceSummary switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) (/clp:PerformanceSummary).

At the end of the build, it outputs a detailed summary like the following.

```
   ...
   14 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                    3 calls
   18 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   3 calls
   22 ms  PostBuildEvent                             1 calls
   28 ms  CleanReferencedProjects                    3 calls
   48 ms  UpdateAssemblyInfo                         1 calls
   51 ms  CoreResGen                                 3 calls
   74 ms  CoreClean                                  3 calls
  103 ms  _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory   2 calls
  177 ms  _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal                  3 calls
  293 ms  CheckPrerequisites                         3 calls
  327 ms  GenerateTemporaryTargetAssembly            1 calls
  329 ms  Clean                                      5 calls
  460 ms  MarkupCompilePass2                         1 calls
  627 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  3 calls
  890 ms  RestorePackages                            3 calls
  891 ms  MarkupCompilePass1                         1 calls
  936 ms  CoreCompile                                4 calls
 4583 ms  Rebuild                                    4 calls
12133 ms  Setupkit                                   1 calls
24258 ms  CompileAndTest                             1 calls
```

Comment: I tried this and it obviously works when building from the command line, but strangely does not produce the same output summary when adding the switch to a MSBuild step in TeamCity (v7.1.5).  I presume you could manually call MSBuild yourself, with a command line build step, but I would have hoped TeamCity would have handled the command line parameters correctly.